# Is there a closed-form expression for the exponential map for SO(n), just like how Rodrigues' rotation formula is for SO(3)?

Tags: lie-groups, rotations, matrix-exponential

Rodrigues' rotation formula is great since it gives us a faster way to compute the exp() and log() operators for SO(3) compared to the Taylor series formulation. I was wondering if there was a generalization of this formula for arbitrary $SO(n)$? Likely not since Rodrigues' formula utilizes the cross product, which only exists in $\mathbb{R}^3$.